# Confused - Binding "this" & closures - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm reading a great [article](https://howtonode.org/what-is-this) on `this` in JavaScript. The author says that the following code is bad:

```
Cart = {
  items: [1,4,2],
  onClick: function () {
    // Do something with this.items.
  }
}
$("#mybutton").click(Cart.onClick);
```

He says that the `click` event doesn't know about the `Cart` object when calling onClick, therefore `this.items` won't be the `[1,4,2]` array that I expect it to be.

The author goes on to say that this code creates a closure and fixes it but I don't understand how the following code fixes the problem.

```
$("#mybutton").click(function () { Cart.onClick() });
```

---

1) In what context (if not `Cart`) does `this` thing we're in if we use the first example.

2) Why does the second example fix the problem?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: Why not make that an answer? :)

Comment: I recommend to read the following sources: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this . When you understand `this`, you will understand the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Some good detail about `this` is given in "*[How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)*"

But, the important part is that the value of `this` is determined when and by how the `function` is invoked.

---

1. By passing the method itself as an argument, accessing it from an object and invoking it become separate acts. This separation is how it loses track of the object it came from – `Cart`.

   The invocation is performed by jQuery. And, for event handlers, [it determines the value of `this` to be the referenced element](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler) (matched by `$("#mybutton")`, in this case):

> *When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; [..]*

2. Rather than passing the method itself, this provides an alternate, wrapping function for jQuery to invoke instead. Within that function's body, accessing the method and invoking it are combined in a single statement.

   Having them combined, the language itself determines the value of `this` as the (last) `Object` before the function – `Cart`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is always *context* of the function call. This is why `$("#mybutton").click(Cart.onClick);` sends mybutton object to the function as `this`. In the second example you call `Cart.onClick()` in its own context; `this` is `Cart`.

You can fix first example like this: `$("#mybutton").click(Cart.onClick.bind(Cart));` to force context to `Cart` object.

If you try `<button onclick="Cart.onClick()...` then `this` is `windows` object.

I hope my explanation helps you.